# Bootstrap Collapse bugged with sidebar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar in my website who opens with a click on a button and close when user click on out of sidebar. i handle it with this:

```
('.collapse-sidenav').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".sidebar").toggleClass("showSideNav");
  });

  $('.sidebar').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('body,html').click(function(e){
     $('.sidebar').removeClass('showSideNav');
  });
```

no problem is , I have a collapsible menu in my sidebar , when i click on my collapsible menu item , it won't work due to this:

```
$('.sidebar').click(function(e){
          e.stopPropagation();
      });
```

if i remove this line , sidebar will close when i click on my menu items! don't know how to fix this!

Comment: It looks like you would want to use a more specific selector than `$('.sidebar')` if all your menu items are nested within it. You could also look at jQuery's `not` operator: https://api.jquery.com/not/

Comment: can you give me an example? im not expert in javascript :D , I tried ` if !event.target.hasClass('menu-item') { e.stopPropagation(); }  `but when i click on my collapsible menu item it will also close the sidebar

Comment: Maybe something like this: `$('.sidebar').not('.sidebar .menu-item').click(function(event) { /*your sidebar code here*/ });`

Comment: after this , when i click on menu-item sidebar is not closed but also my menu-item who is collapsible is not working too

Comment: Ah, sorry to hear that. So that I can better help you with the JavaScript are you able to share the HTML for your menu?